# Is there a way to iterate through certain types of objects on a canvas in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

For example, I've got a bunch of text objects of varying font families on a canvas, can I make some kind of call to iterate through these text objects and alter them?

Comment: If you want a good answer you should probably include code in your question. What have you tried? What (exactly) are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all items on a canvas with the `find_all()` method and then just list them:

```
def get_canvas_items(canvas):
    item_list = canvas.find_all()
    for item in item_list:
        item_type = canvas.type(item)   # e.g. "text", "line", etc.
        item_keys = canvas.itemconfig(item).keys()  # item options
        # Do stuff...
```

Have a look at [effbot: The Tkinter Canvas Widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429102726/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) for additional info on canvas.